# Android Text on Canvas

Tags: android, android-widget, android-canvas

I've created a canvas. And I draw text on a canvas. But when I'm testing on different versions of android, the text looks different. Difference between version 4.х and 2.2.

```
    Bitmap btmText = Bitmap.createBitmap(140, 90, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas cnvText = new Canvas(btmText);
    Typeface tf = tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/font.ttf");

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(tf);
    paint.setTextSize(50);
    cnvText.drawText(text, 0, 5, 0, 55, paint);
```

Text look bigger on android 2.2 than android 4.0.3.

Comment: no. android 2.2 is an emulator with 240dpi, android 4.0.3 is nexus s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be because of different screen densities.

I guess `Paint.setTextSize()` takes size in pixels and not in dp. To display the same size in inches across devices, you'll have to decide the size of the text you wish to display in dp and convert that value to pixels.

```
// The TEXT SIZE expressed in dp
private static final float MYTEXTSIZE = 50.0f;

// Get the screen's density scale
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
// Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
textSizePx = (int) (MYTEXTSIZE * scale + 0.5f);

paint.setTextSize(textSizePx);
```

Comment: Oh !! This looks much better, Thanks

Comment: `paint.setTextSize()` only accepts a float argument.